# Resizing Highcharts data when creating Graph when over 100

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to make it so my graph can show everything fully as currently when I try to show something that is 20 it wont show as the data that is 3000 is taking all the space and making it one large line. I am after trying to make it so that the data showen on graph shows as 3 when 3000 but then on tooltip shows as 3k. But when 5 it should show as 5 on graph but tooltip only as 5.

I cant seem to find out how I can do this.

But here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kzL0phfu/

I think i need to change something here but im not quite sure what.

```
yAxis: {
gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
lineWidth: 0,
min: 0,
gridLineColor: "#808080",
gridLineDashStyle: "Solid",
gridLineWidth: 2,
labels: {
  format: '{value:.2f}',
   style: {
   color: '#c4c4c4',
   font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
  }
}
}
```

Comment: So you want to show shorten version of bigger numbers as axis labels? Did you try to use xAxis.formatter (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter)?

Comment: I am after making it so that it shortness numbers over 99 so that they the x-axis and y-axis is mas of 99. With number like 3000 turning into 3 but in tooltip showing as 3k

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your example, you have several different data points for which you want to set a maximum of 99, but one of those data points, "win rate," can be well over 1000, which skews the chart (and makes the other data points impossible to see).

If you want to show a value for "win rate" that still has a maximum of 99, I'd suggest that you change the data **before** you put it into your Highcharts code.

For example, if you're bringing in this data from an API or database, **first** divide the "win rate" values by 100 **and then** add them to the chart series. You shouldn't need to change your Highcharts code.

So, using your sample data, "win rate" values of 3843 and 6245 would appear as 38.43 and 62.45, making the chart more readable (see below).

[image]

I hope this is helpful. If you're getting your data another way, let me know, and perhaps there's a similar solution we can puzzle out.

Comment: My question is thought how can i place the K at end of it when its over a 1000